# Flutter I want to design the interface like this, can you guys help me? I am designing an about page but I am having problems

Tags: ios, android-layout, mobile, flutter, layout

I have just learned and fluttered and am trying to design an about page. I am having difficulty in the card of flutter. I need a complete demo board to refer to the next issue.

[image]

Comment: you can use `Column` and `ExpansionTile`, see example here: https://flutter.dev/docs/catalog/samples/expansion-tile-sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use package expandable

full code

```
import 'package:expandable/expandable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Expandable Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() {
    return MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("About DTC"),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            loremIpsum,
            softWrap: true,
            overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
          ),
          Card1(),
          Card2(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

const loremIpsum =
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

class Card1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ExpandableNotifier(
        child: ScrollOnExpand(
      scrollOnExpand: false,
      scrollOnCollapse: true,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Card(
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ScrollOnExpand(
                scrollOnExpand: true,
                scrollOnCollapse: false,
                child: ExpandablePanel(
                  tapHeaderToExpand: true,
                  tapBodyToCollapse: true,
                  headerAlignment: ExpandablePanelHeaderAlignment.center,
                  header: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Text(
                        "Service",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2,
                      )),
                  collapsed:
                      Container(), //Text('Service', softWrap: true, maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,),
                  expanded: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                              ListTile(title: Text('Item ')),
                            ]),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                              ListTile(title: Text('Item ')),
                            ]),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                              ListTile(title: Text('Item ')),
                            ]),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                              ListTile(title: Text('Item ')),
                            ]),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                              ListTile(title: Text('Item ')),
                            ]),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                              ListTile(title: Text('Item ')),
                            ]),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  builder: (_, collapsed, expanded) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1, right: 1, bottom: 1),
                      child: Expandable(
                        collapsed: collapsed,
                        expanded: expanded,
                        crossFadePoint: 0,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class Card2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ExpandableNotifier(
        child: ScrollOnExpand(
      scrollOnExpand: false,
      scrollOnCollapse: true,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Card(
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ScrollOnExpand(
                scrollOnExpand: true,
                scrollOnCollapse: false,
                child: ExpandablePanel(
                  tapHeaderToExpand: true,
                  tapBodyToCollapse: true,
                  headerAlignment: ExpandablePanelHeaderAlignment.center,
                  header: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Text(
                        "Contact",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2,
                      )),
                  collapsed:
                      Container(), //Text("Contact", softWrap: true, maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,),
                  expanded: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                          child: Text(
                            'Address : 5F',
                            softWrap: true,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                          )),
                    ],
                  ),
                  builder: (_, collapsed, expanded) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1, right: 1, bottom: 1),
                      child: Expandable(
                        collapsed: collapsed,
                        expanded: expanded,
                        crossFadePoint: 0,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

[image]